# How to get flowId in transform activity in Oracle SOA 12c

Tags: soa

Oracle 12c we have flow id method to keep track of service request. In assign activity I'm able to get flow id using ora:getFlowId() method but in transform activity I don't see such method. So, my question is how can I get this flow id in transform activity ?.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assign a hard code value to flow id in your transform. after transform just have an assign in which override the already populated flow id with the function. This should do the trick.

There is no specific function to get the same in the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like this. Pass the ora:getFlowId() as a parameter to the xquery then assign it inside where ever you want.

```
xquery version "1.0" encoding "utf-8";

(:: OracleAnnotationVersion "1.0" ::)

declare variable $flowId as xs:string external;

declare function local:func($flowId as xs:string)
                             as element() {

  <result>
  {$flowId}
  </result>

};

local:func($flowId as xs:string)
```

This might not answer your question to get flowId directly. But it might be a workaround for your problem.

Hope it helps